# using SalesforceBulk API, batch_status() return 'state': 'Queued'

Tags: bulk-api

While searching the StackExchange for 'Queued' I found that most answers are related to apex code.
In my case I'm using the SalesforceBulk API (through python).

My scenario:
When calling the batch_status(job_id, batch_id) method, in most cases I'm getting 'State': 'Completed', but from time to time I'm getting State': 'Queued'.

How to relate to state?
I couldn't understand from the documentation if those jobs will get out of the queue automatically and I just need to check the status from time to time, or should I trigger something to get them out of the queue and to be processed.

Comment: What Python library are you using? Some have nice convenience methods to abstract away polling state for you.

Comment: I'm using salesforce-bulk 2.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Its a Job Queue, The queue will process when the system has available resource. The only thing you can do is [Abort](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_jobs_abort.htm?search_text=abort) after a job is queued. You cannot trigger it asap, force it run now or prioritize it.

Have a look at this [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_batches_interpret_status.htm?search_text=abort) that will help you interpret what batch state mean.

Comment: So if "The queue will process when the system has available resource." isn't it better to wait and check for state till it will be completed, instead of Abort and retry?

Comment: @Gil I have rephrased my statement to give clear context. Yes you have to wait till it get exxecuetd.

Comment: Thanks @Pranay, I will run batch_status() from time to time till state will turn Completed or Failed

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the platform's timing in terms of processing Bulk API batches, and there's no action you need to take to move them into processing once you've finished uploading the batch.

`salesforce_bulk` has a convenience method so that you don't have to poll or inspect the batch status yourself. Just do

```
bulk.wait_for_batch(
    job_id,
    batch_id,
    timeout=your_desired_timeout_in_seconds,
    sleep_interval=how_long_to_sleep_between_checks
)
```

The last two parameters are optional. `salesforce_bulk` will poll and sleep for you until the batch completes (either successfully or not). You can then call `bulk.get_batch_results(batch_id, job_id)` to get back the successes or failures.

Comment: Thanks @David, sounds like a good idea